# How to build a custom tab navigation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

I am trying to build a navigation/menu system in which users can create custom tabs similar to yahoo mail. To be more descriptive, a user would have a fixed set of tabs when on the menu and then add tabs to the menu and navigate freely within tabs keeping context.

I would prefer to do this in jquery but am open to other frameworks as well.

Answer (score 2):

check out [jquery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html). I haven't yet used it in production, but I've played around with their tabs and found it was extremely simple to set up.

Comment: It has some good UI tools but dont see a dynamic tab tool anywhere. Its all static tabs.

Comment: use the jquery tools for the tabs, and stock jquery methods such as append() to dynamically add additional tabs.